# Method removing more items that requried

Tags: javascript

I am inputting an array with

```
[one, two, ""]
```

I want to remove the "" so that i return

```
[one, two]
```

But it is only returning

```
[one]
```

I have tried the filter multiple times with multiple scenarios, and it did not work, this is the closest I have gotten to an answer. How can I fix it so that array2 return [one, two]

```
function removingEmptyString(array)
{
    var array2;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] == "" || array[i] == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            array2 = array[i];

        }

    return array2;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a break in your for loop.

```
   function removingEmptyString(array)
    {
        var array2 = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                if(array[i] != "" && array[i] != null)
                    {
                      array2.push(array[i])
                    }

            }

        return array2;

        }
```

Comment: You should do `array2.push(array[i])`

Comment: Edited. Almost forgot about `push`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create and return a whole new array, just `splice` out the value;

```
function removingEmptyString(array)
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] == "")
            array.splice(i, 1);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Internally `splice` creates a new array. If you want a memory optimized version of splice you need to swap items when you remove one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the values onto the array. So instead of

```
var array2;
...
array2 = array[i];
```

Do

```
var array2 = []; // Or var array2 = new Array();
...
array2.push(array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array with its `filter()` method:

```
 var a = [one, two, ""];
 var b = a.filter(function(elem) {
   // if you want to filter 'falsy' values:
   //   return elem;
   return elem !== "";
 });
```